# Как посредством API Woocommerce передавать информацию по каждому сделанному заказу

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Сайт на Wordpress и Woocommerce. Не понимаю что именно нужно сделать, чтобы посредством API передавать информацию по каждому сделанному заказу.
Вид передачи в одну строку с идентификатором, с содержанием определённой информации по заказу (артикул, цена, адрес доставки и прочее..)
Как формируется данная информация по заказу, что если не совпадают какие то параметры вордпресса с параметрами, которые нужно передать? Где вообще искать то, что формируется в эту передаваемую строку?
Читал про АПИ - не понял ровно ничего..

Answer (score 1):

Для получения информации о состоянии заказов можно воспользоваться REST API.

Полный перечень заказов доступен по ссылке:

`http://site.test/wp-json/wc/v3/orders`

Информация о заказе 428:

`http://test.test/wp-json/wc/v3/orders/428`

Для того, чтобы ссылки начали работать, необходимо произвести аутентификацию, как [написано в руководстве](http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#authentication).